# How to prevent "index out of range" when I need the items around the index position?

Tags: c#

I have an array of strings which represents the lines of a textfile. Now I want to search the line where my given argument occurs and return this line plus the four adjacent lines.
The problem occurs when my searched string is found in the last or first two indexes. Obviously this is because I want the index[i+2] when there is none.
Ideally, if the last line is the prime one, it should return only this and the two lines before it because there aren't two after it.

So is there a Best Practice how to solve this issue other then adding an if-statement in front of every of the five line inside the "contains"-if-statement?

`ReadAsString` converts the content of the textfile into the array of strings `_textAsString`

```
public string[] GetNearestInstructions(string foo)
{
    try
    {
        string[] stringsToReturn = new string[5];
        if (!this.ReadAsString())
            return null;
        else if (foo == null)
            return null;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _textAsString.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_textAsString[i].Contains(foo))
                {
                    stringsToReturn[0] = _textAsString[i - 2];
                    stringsToReturn[1] = _textAsString[i - 1];
                    stringsToReturn[2] = _textAsString[i];
                    stringsToReturn[3] = _textAsString[i + 1];
                    stringsToReturn[4] = _textAsString[i + 2];
                }
            }

            if (stringsToReturn != null)
                return stringsToReturn;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the first + last indices as needed. See code below. Also I changed `stringsToReturn` to a `List` because it is more convenient, and because there is no point in always returning an array of 5 items if there are fewer than 5.

```
List<string> stringsToReturn = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < _textAsString.Length; i++)
{
    if (_textAsString[i].Contains(foo))
    {
        var firstIndex = Math.Max(0, i - 2);
        var lastIndex = Math.Min(_textAsString.Length - 1, i + 2);

        for (int j = firstIndex; j <= lastIndex; j++)
            stringsToReturn.Add(_textAsString[j]);

        return stringsToReturn.ToArray();
    }
}

// foo not found
return null;
```

Comment: The answer of @500 was the fastest and helped me understand the solution, but this seems to be a better solution with the containing `List`.

Answer (score 3):

You might do something like

```
...
if (_textAsString[i].Contains(foo))
{
   int rangoLow = Math.Max(i - 2, 0);
   int rangeHigh = Math.Min(i + 2, _textAsString.Length - 1);
   for (int i = rangeLow; i <= rangeHigh; i++)
   {
      stringsToReturn[i - rangeLow] = _textAsString[i];
}
```

Comment: this changes the possible desired output format of a fixed length string array

Comment: This is meant as an illustration of a hint, not production ready code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you need the result as `array` in the exact same format as you are returning it right now, that is with null items at begin or end, this would be the way I would do it:

```
public static string[] GetNearestInstructions(string foo)
{
    if (foo != null && this.ReadAsString())
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(_textAsString, foo);

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            string[] stringsToReturn = new string[5];

            stringsToReturn[0] = index > 1 ? _textAsString[index - 2] : null;
            stringsToReturn[1] = index > 0 ? _textAsString[index - 1] : null;
            stringsToReturn[2] = _textAsString[index];
            stringsToReturn[3] = index < _textAsString.Length - 1 ? _textAsString[index + 1] : null;
            stringsToReturn[4] = index < _textAsString.Length - 2 ? _textAsString[index + 2] : null;

            return stringsToReturn;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Things get easier if you are fine with changing the number of returned items, see the other answers then.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that if _textAsString is string (not collection of strings), then this function should take char as parameter, and return collection of chars (or single string).